# How to use DRACOLoader with GLTFLoader in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf

I have a use case in which I am trying to load a GLTF file which is compressed using DRACO-Compression. I am able to run it using plain javascript but I am facing issues integrating the loader with ReactJs.

What I am doing:

- Copying the draco library from here into my application's scope - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/libs/draco
- Copying the DRACOLoader.js from here into my application's scope - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/DRACOLoader.js
- Exporting it as a THREE.DRACOLoader Module in my application where I need it

The error I am getting - **DracoDecoderModule is not defined**

In my app, this is how I am importing:

```
  import DRACOLoader from './DRACOLoader'
  DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath('./draco/')
```

Answer (score 13):

It is recommended to use https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/ as the decoder source directory, e.g.:

```
const draco = new DRACOLoader();
draco.setDecoderConfig({ type: 'js' });
draco.setDecoderPath('https://www.gstatic.com/draco/v1/decoders/');
```

See example https://github.com/google/draco/tree/master/javascript/example.

Answer (score 6):

Relative paths won't work. One way to achieve this is by either hosting your `draco_wasm_wrapper.js` on like aws or something like that or you could try the following:

```
npm i -S three // make sure you have the latest threejs package v2 and up
```

Import your dependencies:

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader'
```

Create and configue your draco loader:

```
const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/libs/draco/'); // use a full url path
```

Create and configure your gltf loader:

```
const gltf = new GLTFLoader();
gltf.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

// then you can load your glb file
const glbPath = 'your glb file'
gltf.load(glbPath, function(gltf) {
  console.log(gltf)
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I like the answer from @marrion luaka (and upvoted it) but referencing locally.

Only changed:

```
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/examples/js/libs/draco/'); // use a full url path
```

To this:

`dracoLoader.setDecoderPath( '../node_modules/three/examples/js/libs/draco/gltf/' );`

Answer (score 3):

Host the draco folder in cloud then

```
import DRACOLoader from './DRACOLoader';
DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath(path to hosted draco folder);
```

worked for me.

if you do like this,

```
DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath('./draco/')
```

then react will take it as,

```
DRACOLoader.setDecoderPath('localhost:3000/draco/');
```

so it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked directly for me on three@0.115.0 so I used:

```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader';
import * as THREE from 'three';

// draco
const draco = new DRACOLoader()
draco.setDecoderPath('../node_modules/three/examples/js/libs/draco/gltf/');
draco.setDecoderConfig({ type: 'js' });
export const dracoLoader = draco;

// gltf
const gltf = new GLTFLoader();
gltf.setDRACOLoader( dracoLoader );
export const gltfLoader = gltf;
```

---

BONUS for those who like promises, I've also been making my loaders return promises with the following:

```
function promisify(loader, onProgress) {
  function promiseLoader(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      loader.load(url, resolve, onProgress, reject);
    });
  }
  return {
    originalLoader: loader,
    load: promiseLoader,
  };
}
```

Example usage:

```
import { FBXLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader';

export const fbxLoader = promisify(new FBXLoader());
```

Then elsewhere:

```
import { fbxLoader } from './loaders'

fbxLoader.load('cat.fbx').then(model => {
  console.log(model)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another option (for `React` only).

I copied the three required files from node_modules to public, in a folder called 'draco'.

```
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()
const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader()  // allow for DRACO compression
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/draco/')
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use [https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/[version]/](https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/%5Bversion%5D/) as the decoder source directory, e.g.:

```
const draco = new DRACOLoader();
draco.setDecoderConfig({ type: 'js' });
draco.setDecoderPath('https://www.gstatic.com/draco/versioned/decoders/1.5.6/');
```

Using the versioned `www.gstatic.com` WASM and Javascript decoders is recommended since `v1.4.1`, as stated [here](https://github.com/google/draco#version-141-release).

Answer (score 0):

I am using **Webpack** in a similar way to how **Create React App** uses it. Here is how I got the Draco decoder path working.

1. In your app's `public` folder, create a new folder called `draco`.
2. Download the four files found in the [Three.js Draco Examples](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/libs/draco/gltf) and move them into your `public/draco` folder.
3. Use this code:

```js
// Imports
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader'
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/DRACOLoader.js';

// Create a new DRACO loader (for decompressing compressed GLTF models)
const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();

// Set the DRACO loader's decoder path to the `public/draco` folder
// NB: You have to manually download and copy/paste the files from 
// https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/libs/draco/gltf
// into this folder.
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('./draco/');

// Create a new GLTF loader
const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();

// Use the DRACO loader with the GLTF loader
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
   const loader = new GLTFLoader();
   const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
    
   dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('/node_modules/three/examples/jsm/libs/draco/');
    
   loader.setDRACOLoader( dracoLoader );
```

I hope it will be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Vite and you don't want to use a CDN you need to copy the `three/examples/jsm/libs/draco/gltf/` folder into your static / public folder. Then you can set the path using the [new URL(url, import.meta.url)](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url) method

```
// Imports
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { DRACOLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/DRACOLoader.js'

// Create loader
const dracoDecoderPath = new URL('./draco/gltf', import.meta.url).href
const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader()
dracoLoader.setDecoderPath(dracoDecoderPath + '/')
// This also works
//dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('draco/gltf/')

const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader()
gltfLoader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader)
```